# can't use 2 js functions with sleep between them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an angular form where the user types text and while he does it the text lable below say "user is typing...".

Then it waits for 200 mili seconds and the text lable goes blank (the "user is typing" disappear).

I am doing it with angular ng-change directive.
my code is below.

the problem is that for some reason there is a problem with the help method I wrote for running 2 methods with sleep in between them.
for some reason the text "user is typing..." does not disappear after a short sleep.

why is that?

thanks

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.myFunc = function() {
    runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem(function (){$scope.text='user is typing...';},function (){$scope.text='';},200);
  };

  var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem = function(foo1,foo2, time) {
    var sleep =function (time) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }
    foo1();
    sleep(time).then(() => {
      foo2();
    });
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Write something in the input field:</p>
    <input type="text" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems to be related to your code being out of angular scope by the time the timeout is executed, try to use `$scope.$apply` inside your timer callback...

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you need to call `$scope.$apply()` in order for the changes to the `$scope.text` variable to take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As André Vale and Titus mentioned in the comments, you're outside your scope application cycle, so Angular doesn't know to do a "dirty check" after you've updated scope.

```
var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem=function(foo1,foo2, time) {
  var sleep = function (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }
  foo1();
  sleep(time).then(() => {
    foo2();
    $scope.$apply();
  });
}
```

Your `sleep` function approximates [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), which is Promise-based; you could easily switch to it, and also take advantage of the fact that it will invoke the function within an `$apply` block by default:

```
// Inject the $timeout service in your controller.
var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem=function(foo1, foo2, time) {
  foo1();
  $timeout(foo2, time);
}
```

If you wanted to make this *fully* Promise-compatible, delaying `foo1` if it returns a promise, and aborting if it rejects, then you could rephrase it like this:

```
// Inject $timeout and $q.
var runTwoFunctionWithSleepBetweenThem=function(foo1, foo2, time) {
  $q.when(foo1()).then(() => $timeout(foo2, time));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define service for this behavior:

```
app.service('Sleep', Sleep);
Sleep.$inject = [$timeout]

function Sleep($timeout) {
  return time =>new Promise((ok) => {$timeout(ok, time);});
}
```

Usage(after inject `Sleep` service as `sleep`):

```
foo1();
sleep(1000).then(foo2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using underscore then check out _.debounce.  Also people are correct about $scope.$apply();

```html
var time = 200;
var func2 = _.debounce(function(){
  $scope.text = "";
  $scope.$apply();
}, time);
$scope.myFunc = function() {
  $scope.text='user is typing...';
  func2();
};
```